# react: functional component that ignores prop changes until callback is triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a controlled component that I want to use to trigger an optimistic update, and, while the update is being performed, it should use it's internal state and ignore all changes to it's main prop, and once a callback is executed then it can again use the provided prop as values.
I tried to encode this logic on a hook using `useMemo`, `useRef`, and different setStates but without success. I think it is because the used ref does not survive long enough (the component is re-rendered like 3 times between the update trigger and the callback execution) and at some point it gets re-created with the new value coming from props.

Here is the hook that I done so far:

```js
function useOptimistic(incoming) {
  const [state, setState] = useState('INITIAL')
  const ref = useRef(incoming)
  const value = useMemo(() => ref.current, [state])
  const setUpdating = (value) => {
    setState('UPDATING')
    ref.current = value
  }
  const setUpdated = () => setState('UPDATED')
  return { state: value, setUpdating, setUpdated }
}
```

The reason is because I am using graphql and a toggle component. When I click on the toggle component I trigger the graphql request and you can see the change with the local state, but while the query is being executed the component is re-rendered 3 or 4 times, and the toggle shows the state from the "old-data", when the request completes then it comes back to the correct state. What I want is to avoid this intermediary weird changes.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (Obviously, you wouldn't have the graphql part, but you can mock up a delayed operation.)

Comment: Please show the usage example of this hook so people can better understand your intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this should do it:

```
const initialState = { updating: false }

function useOptimistic(incoming) {
  const [innerState, setInnerState] = useState(initialState)

  const setUpdating = (value) => setInnerState({ updating: true, value })
  const setUpdated = () => setInnerState(initialState)
  const state = innerState.updating ? innerState.value : incoming

  return { state, setUpdating, setUpdated }
}
```

Live Example (based on T.J. Crowder's answer), just to show that it's not really necessary to have stable functions for something like this ;-).

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React;

const initialState = { updating: false }

function useOptimistic(incoming) {
  const [innerState, setInnerState] = useState(initialState)

  const setUpdating = (value) => setInnerState({ updating: true, value })
  const setUpdated = () => setInnerState(initialState)
  const state = innerState.updating ? innerState.value : incoming

  return { state, setUpdating, setUpdated }
}

function Example() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(1);
    const {state, setUpdating, setUpdated} = useOptimistic(value);
    const triggerUpdate = () => {
        const newValue = value + 1;
        setUpdating(newValue);
        setTimeout(() => {
            setValue(newValue);
            setUpdated(); // <=== Note that despite the fact that this function
                          // is not stable, this still works perfectly fine ;-)
        }, 1000);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <div>value: {value}</div>
            <div>state: {state}</div>
            <input type="button" onClick={triggerUpdate} value="Trigger Update" />
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A ref will only be *created* once, when the component using the hook is first mounted, so you were right to try to store the pending state in a ref (although it could also be stored in state). You'd also probably be best off putting the state setters in a ref as well, since making them stable (like `useState` does) is useful to consumers of the hook, so I'll use the ref for the pending value as well.

The main problem with your hook, I think, is that it always uses the value from `ref.current`, but it only sets `ref.current` to `incoming` when the component using the hook is **first** mounted. So it ignores subsequent changes to `incoming` (whether or not it's in the updating state).

The change I'd make (other than using a boolean rather than strings for the flag) is to use your "updating" flag to choose what to return as `state`, returning the then-current `incoming` when not updating, or the optimistic pending value if updating. See comments:

```
function useOptimistic(incoming) {
    // A flag for whether we're in the "udating" state
    const [updatingFlag, setUpdatingFlag] = useState(false)
    // Our instance data
    const instance = useRef(null);
    if (!instance.current) {
        // Only happens on first call, this object is created once
        instance.current = {
            // The pending value
            pendingValue: null,
            // Set the pending value and go into the updating state
            setUpdating: (value) => {
                instance.current.pendingValue = value;
                setUpdatingFlag(true);
            },
            // Exit the updating state
            setUpdated: () => {
                setUpdatingFlag(false);
                instance.current.pendingValue = null;
            },
        };
    }
    // The state value we'll return: the input prop, or the one from our
    // instance data
    const state = updatingFlag ? instance.current.pendingValue : incoming;

    // Grab our setters and return them with the state
    const { setUpdating, setUpdated } = instance.current;
    return { state, setUpdating, setUpdated };
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React;

function useOptimistic(incoming) {
    // A flag for whether we're in the "udating" state
    const [updatingFlag, setUpdatingFlag] = useState(false)
    // Our instance data
    const instance = useRef(null);
    if (!instance.current) {
        // Only happens on first call, this object is created once
        instance.current = {
            // The pending value
            pendingValue: null,
            // Set the pending value and go into the updating state
            setUpdating: (value) => {
                instance.current.pendingValue = value;
                setUpdatingFlag(true);
            },
            // Exit the updating state
            setUpdated: () => {
                setUpdatingFlag(false);
                instance.current.pendingValue = null;
            },
        };
    }
    // The state value we'll return: the input prop, or the one from our
    // instance data
    const state = updatingFlag ? instance.current.pendingValue : incoming;

    // Grab our setters and return them with the state
    const { setUpdating, setUpdated } = instance.current;
    return { state, setUpdating, setUpdated };
}

function Example() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(1);
    const {state, setUpdating, setUpdated} = useOptimistic(value);
    const triggerUpdate = () => {
        const newValue = value + 1;
        setUpdating(newValue);
        setTimeout(() => {
            setValue(newValue);
            setUpdated(); // <=== Note that the stability of the setters is what
                          // lets me use this here, it wouldn't be correct if
                          // the setters weren't stable
        }, 1000);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <div>value: {value}</div>
            <div>state: {state}</div>
            <input type="button" onClick={triggerUpdate} value="Trigger Update" />
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The advantage of this solution is that it avoids creating new functions on each update. meaning that `setUpdating` and `setUpdated` will remain referentially equal in different updates. Which is cool, of course. However, I don't think that the issue that the OP was having is related to this...

Comment: @Josep - No, I think it was primarily the `useMemo` and the fact that the OP'shook didn't use the updated `incoming`. But the point is that the above shows a hook that does what they said they wanted, and also shows creating stable setters. :-)

Comment: That's awesome, but IMHO I think that it's best to show the simplest way of solving the issue so that the OP understands what's the real problem is. I've updated my answer with your example, just to show that it's not necessarily true that the setters must be stable for this to work.

Comment: @Josep - Good point, the way your implementation is written, you don't *need* setter stability (because you're relying on the stability from `useState`). Fair enough for that specific implementation.

Comment: Both proposed solutions look like can work, but they don't. The one proposed by @Josep is very close to what I initially tried, but don't work. And the proposed solution here does not work either. I have added a couple of logs and I can see how the ref object is being re-created. I mentioned that, once the query is triggered the component tree is re-executed several times. For some executions I also get this react error: react_devtools_backend.js:2450 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. So react is probably disposing even the reference during this updates.

Comment: @Danielo515 - Again, you'll need to provide us with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. React won't normally unmount and remount components in a rendering tree, so there must be something unusual going on in your case.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I will try to create a repro example. I was using react-table, and the component I wanted to avoid loose it's state was a cell on a table, so very nested one. I solved it by memoizing the table columns, which is a performance improvement, but should not be mandatory to avoid loosing refs references.